# EE Failed to activate virtual core keyboard: 2(EE)

Tags: keyboard, arch-linux, xorg, manjaro

I upgraded my Manjaro Linux using command

```
   sudo pacman -Syu
```

then when I rebooteEE Failed to activate virtual core keyboard: 2(EE)d a day later, I got blank screen with blinking cursor and also sometimes

```
[drm:drm_atomic_helper_commit_cleanup_done [drm_kms_helper] *ERROR* [CRTC:26:pipe A] flip done timed out
```

I am able to access the terminal using Alt-Ctrl-F2

On checking journalctl, I am getting this error:-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zdrbh.jpg

I googled a lot. I checked my space. it has 46% free using df command and I have set /tmp to 777 acc to one of questions blog, still error persists these seems to be unrelated. What shall I do?